# Determine Windows file-system on GPT partition

Tags: gpt

I have a laptop with SSD which has Windows 10 installed. I booted the laptop from USB flash drive into Ubuntu 14.04.3 and tried to find out the file system on partition 4. According to `gdisk` it has partition code 0x0700, which means that it is 0x07(0x0700/0x0100) in MBR codes which means HPFS/NTFS/exFAT. This is in accord with `gdisk` manual which says that `codes for all varieties of FAT and NTFS partition correspond to a single GPT code(entered as 0x0700 in sgfdisk)`. According to `parted` it's `msftdata`. `Parted` seems to gather its information by looking the data from partition. `fdisk -s /dev/sda4`, which uses the same principle as `parted`, finds that the file-system is `PE32 executable`. Finally I tried to get any additional information with `ntfsinfo`, but looks like that `ntfsinfo` wants the file-system to be mounted:

[image: ntfsinfo]

For example `dumpe2fs` can be used on unmounted file-systems. One could assume that this is a NTFS partition, but for some reason the partition is not mounted:

[image: mount]

In short, how to determine Windows file-system on GPT disk partition? Or is there a way to check from Linux if this partition is encrypted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out, that file-system on `/dev/sda4` partition was corrupted and not encrypted. I was able to fix the partition with `ntfsfix /dev/sda4`. Output of `file -s /dev/sda4` and `ntfsinfo` once the file-system is fixed can be seen below:

```
root@ubuntu:~# file -s /dev/sda4
/dev/sda4: x86 boot sector
root@ubuntu:~# ntfsinfo -vm /dev/sda4 | head
Volume Information 
    Name of device: /dev/sda4
    Device state: 11
    Volume Name: 
    Volume State: 91
    Volume Flags: 0x0000
    Volume Version: 3.1
    Sector Size: 512
    Cluster Size: 4096
    Index Block Size: 4096
root@ubuntu:~#
```

Answer (score 1):

If the kernel will support mounting it, you can just try

```
mkdir /mnt/tmp
mount /dev/sda4 /mnt/tmp
```

and then do `df -T` to check it.

If not, you could try `file -s /dev/sda4` to get more information.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to mount this partition. I use NTFS driver version 2.1.31 and `mount -t ntfs /dev/sda4 /mnt` results in `NTFS signature is missing`. I added additional information to my initial post.

Comment: If the kernel's autodetect fails (as is indicated by the `You must specify the filesystem type` message), then `file -s` may provide some information. If not (it says `data` without more details if it can't identify the argument) then you would have to make an educated guess from research, then find out how to identify that hypothetical filesystem.

Comment: As seen in my initial post, `file -s /dev/sda4` says `P32 executable (native) Intel 80386, for MS Windows`. I'm afraid that the file-system in encrypted, but I don't know how to check this from Linux or this is possible at all..

Comment: `file` is probably picking up the Windows boot sector/bootloader, then, and not FS stuff. All I can recommend is to research what it could be, then try to find individual checking methods for the possibilities.